# Meta viewport : width=device-width or initial-scale=1 or both

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport

For a fully responsive web design, which one of the following meta viewport declaration should I use :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I would like the design to fit the screen after rotating the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
>   a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
>   device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
>   scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
>   values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
>   or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and
>   user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the
>   page in or out

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this website [link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972) is pointing out some problem with using `width=device-width` and `initial-scale=1.0` together : they tell that it's safer to use `initial-scale=1.0` only to avoid devices rotating issues. It looks like more natural for me. But, some "real" websites like CSS-Tricks are using only `width=device-width`, so finally I still looking for the best practice...

Comment: I'm honestly not sure there is a "best practice" for the meta tag. It basically comes down to how you desire it to work with your website. Perhaps you do not need width if it is causing undesired results for you when rotating a device.